Pseudoinversion giving poor predictions, converges with smaller matrix
I'm having an issue where running pseudoinversion as a means of predicting the values of certain phenotypes using methylation data gives extremely large numbers, very pooly predicting said values, unless the matrix is significantly cut down.
Specifically, I have two initial matrices, trait_data and meth_data. I select a single subsection of each to set aside as the test animal. I then utilize pseudoinversion to generate a predictions for the trait data, as shown below. When dealing with ~20 traits, the predictions are quite accurate. But when dealing with ~40 traits, I am literally getting numbers in the billions for values which should be around 1. How can I resolve this issue, or is this to be expected using this method? I am basing this method off of the paper 'The methylome of buccal epithelial cells is influenced by age, sex, and physiological properties'
'''
    #leave out one animal
    train_trait = np.delete(trait_data, n, 0)
    train_meth = np.delete(meth_data, n, 0)
    
    test_trait = trait_data[n]
    test_meth = meth_data[n]

    train_trait_pinv = np.linalg.pinv(train_trait)

    site_coef = np.dot(train_trait_pinv, train_meth) #Coefficient = Pinv(Trait_Train) * Meth_Train
    coef_pinv = np.linalg.pinv(site_coef)

    pred_trait = np.dot(test_meth, coef_pinv) #Trait_Pred = Meth_Test * Pinv(Site Coef)

'''
Edit: here are the array sizes
train_trait.shape = (45, 55)
train_meth.shape = (45, 284381)
test_trait.shape = (55,)
test_meth.shape = (284381,)


Pinv is computing a pseudomatrix inverse? Like $P(X) = (X^TX)^{-1}X^T$ and effectively being OLS regression? Why does it not work? What is the discrepancy that you observe? Is it not the same as OLS? Does the matrix inverse not work well?

How many samples do you have, is it more or less than the traits? Is there possibly collinearity in the columns?

Why do you again invert the coefficients? (when you compute coef_pinv out of site_coef)

It's not that it doesn't work, it's just giving me very poor predictions for a large number of traits. When I cut down on the number of traits it works well. I've updated the array sizes to make things a bit more clear. There is likely collinearity in the columns, the filtering has 2 stages and one of them is removing collinearity (the second is just about choosing more informative traits). I invert the coefficient to align the matrix sizes and for readability in manuscript form. The code works but this intial inaccuracy makes me concerned is all, and I felt I should seek out a 2nd opinion.

I'm not familiar with this method, and the website for that paper seems not to have a PDF (https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/37781740/). Can you tell us a little more about the procedure? As @SextusEmpiricus points out in their answer, it is slightly nonstandard to us in stats to be using two separate pseudo-inversions.

Also, wherever you have np.dot(np.linalg.pinv(A),B,) it will be much more numerically stable to use np.linalg.lstsq(A,B)[0].

The second pseudo inverse is effectively just scaling the found coefficients by their dot product. So if you had site_coef $\beta = [1,2,3]$ then it becomes as coef_pinv $INV(\beta) = [1,2,3]^T/(14)$. Why you would like to do that and how the 'create more inaccuracy' helps is not clear. That the predictions can become incredibly erroneous is clear, because you are dividing the estimate by some factor that can be very large or small.

I can say at the very least, on a shallow level, removing that second pseudoinverse and changing nothing else leads to the matrices not aligning properly. The 'create more inaccuracy' statement was misguided though. Readability is more likely the root motivation, I also find it strange honestly but I'm trying to follow the methods strictly for the original paper.

@EpicCabbage what do you mean by 'not alligning properly' (and why should you use a pseudoinverse to solve it)? Maybe you just need to apply some transpose somewhere?

Yeah it would work if I utilized a transpose. I added to my original post the dimensions of the matrices involved to make things a bit more explicit. I actually was originally doing that, but I've been told to follow the methods directly so I have incorporated the two fold pseudoinversion. Apologies that I can't be more helpful, I'll spend some time looking more into the motiviation behind these decisions..

I thought that the coëfficiënts where gonna be a vector, but I see now that it is a matrix. Still, also for a matrix, the use of the pseudoinverse is gonna make that the coëfficiënts have little to do with a good estimate. Whatever the reason is that you are applying this second pseudoinverse, you should not expect it to be a good estimate of the coëfficiënts in a linear predictor.

Got it, thanks. I had previously developed an alternative model using only a single pseudoinversion and transposition which is giving better results, but as I was advised to use this method I had assumed I was simply misunderstanding something.

@EpicCabbage I couldn't get a copy of the referenced article. Did they use the double pseudoinverse method that you were recommended to use?

Yes, the code I used is a direct copy of the formulas used in the publication for the analysis.

@EpicCabbage it could be a typo in that article, or do they argue somewhere about the equation and that they do a second inverse on purpose?

Your code seems to be making one too many inversions.
Try it without the following lines
coef_pinv = np.linalg.pinv(site_coef)
pred_trait = np.dot(test_meth, coef_pinv) #Trait_Pred = Meth_Test * Pinv(Site Coef)

and use instead
pred_trait = np.dot(test_meth, site_coef) #Trait_Pred = Meth_Test * Site_Coef


About the article 'The methylome of buccal epithelial cells is influenced by age, sex, and physiological properties'
I could not get a copy of the article to read myself what happened there, but searching around I could find some supplementary materials on GitHub  https://github.com/giuliaprotti/Methylation_BuccalCells/tree/main and it explains a lot.
The relevant piece of code is
for (i in 1:178){

    Xtrain = as.matrix(X[-i, ])
    Xtest = as.matrix(X[i, ])

    Ytrain = as.matrix(Y[-i, ])
    
    C = pinv(Ytrain) %*% Xtrain
    Ypred[[i]] = Xtest %*% pinv(C)
}

This is different from what you did. The first pseudo inverse is applied to Y and not to X.
So your code would be equivalent to
C = pinv(Xtrain) %*% Ytrain 
Ypred[[i]] = Xtest %*% pinv(C)

Instead of
C = pinv(Ytrain) %*% Xtrain
Ypred[[i]] = Xtest %*% pinv(C)

Note that taking the inverse $^+$ twice will be sort of a cancellation. Using the properties $$(A B)^+ = B^+  A^+ \\ (A^+)^+ = A$$ then you get:
$$C^+ = (Y^+  X)^+ = X^+ (Y^+)^+ = X^+  Y$$
Using $(Y^+  X)^+$ Instead of $X^+  Y$ is probably because it makes the computations easier, e.g prevent round-off errors or underflow/overflow errors, or it reduces the number of computations with large arrays.

 This property $(A B)^+ = B^+  A^+$ is not always true (e.g. when n>p in the example below). The code below demonstrates this.

library(pracma)
set.seed(1)
n = 177   # observations
p = 7     # number of factors
ny = 28   # number of dependent variables 

### some data
x = matrix(rnorm(n*p), ncol = p)
y = matrix(rnorm(n*ny), ncol = ny)

### lm as comparison 
lm(y[,1] ~ 0 + x)

### doesn't work
pinv(pinv(y) %*% x)[,1]

### works
pinv(x) %*% y[,1]
pinv(x) %*% pinv(pinv(y))[,1] 

### however, if p>n 
### then the double inverse does work
### and the result is equal to 
### minimal norm regression
### like the `mnls` function below
lmeVarComp::mnls(x,y[,1])



About the edit, I now have doubts about the conditions for $(A B)^+ = B^+  A^+$, when I try it out then I can not make if work. It requires n<p (more parameters than observations), but in that case there is no good prediction.

I tried implementing this directly, substituting Ytrain for train_trait, etc., but ended up getting the same code as I had used before. In the original paper they utilize this same algorithm twice, first in the context I have provided, and seperately to try and solve for the methylation data. I am attempting to solve for the trait data here, so the prediction matrix should correspond to the trait. I could send you a copy of the paper if that helps, if you give me somewhere to address it too.

@EpicCabbage I see now that you have $p=284381$ features and $n=46$ observations. So you are not performing an OLS regression but a minimal norm regression. In that case the method from the article is correct, as the property $(A B)^+ = B^+  A^+$ applies. But note that you should use the algorithm from the GitHub code and not the formula that you used which is different (it may have been wrong in the article, or you may have misread it)

@EpicCabbage So if p>n then we have $ (Y^+  X)^+ = X^+  Y$ and you can use either of them (and probably they use the first because it computes easier). However, your code is using $ (X^+  Y)^+$.

Ah, that finally makes sense, thank you
